# What to do when uncertain regarding a Bracha on dessert during a bread meal?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, meal-seudah, bread

If you are having a bread-meal and you have dessert in front of you, but you are uncertain if the homotzie covered it - what do you do?

Don't eat it?
Eat it without a Bracha?
Say shehakol (in the case that you don't know what the bracha is) and eat it?
Some other option?

Comment: stick it on a bit of bread then eat it. Definitely doesn't require a separate b'racha then..

More practically, first say Birkat Hamazon. Then eat it when it definitely does require its own b'racha.

Comment: How would saying shehakol help?

Comment: @CashCow Are you allowed to (first say birkat hamazon)?, you probably need another step to do something else before saying the next brocho

Comment: You could say Birkat Hamazon then take the dessert into a different room to eat it, if there's one available.

Otherwise, just eat it together with a bit of bread. You don't have to make them into a sandwich: take a bite of bread and then a bite of dessert... 

That you're eating it at the same time makes it part of the "meal" that the hamotzi is covering.

Comment: @CashCow How much bread? Thanks

Comment: @CashCow Why would the dessert need to be in a different room if you already bentched on the meal?

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not one would make a Beracha on it is subject to a dispute of the Rishonim. Tosefos to [Berachos 12a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=12&format=pdf) s.v. לא לאתויי נהמא cites a dispute between the Rif and the Ri about whether or not one makes a *beracha rishona* when unsure if a previous blessing covered it, with the Rif saying no and the Ri saying yes.

The Rif is understood according to the "simple" understanding of *safek berachos lehakel*, that we are lenient when there is a question regarding blessings. R' Akiva Eiger in the Gilyon HaShas there, citing the Maharsha to Pesachim 102a, explains the logic of the Ri that *safek berachos lehakel* only applies to blessings on *mitzvos*, in which the blessing does not prevent fulfillment of the *mitzvah*. But when it comes to eating, where it is forbidden to eat without a blessing, the blessing made out of doubt is not for nothing - it resolves the doubt and enables one to eat. Therefore one would make the appropriate blessing.

Shulchan Aruch [Orech Chaim 209:3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6597) rules like the Rif, to not make a new blessing, and that is common practice.

However, there is an alternative solution to avoid this doubt. Shulchan Aruch [Orech Chaim 177:3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5153), in resolution to a similar doubt (whether *hamotzi* covers fruit during the meal), writes that one could eat the first bite of fruit with bread and continue to eat the rest without bread and without a blessing. The same could be applied here, to start with eating the first bite together with bread. (Be'ur Halacha 177 s.v. Tov writes that one should preferably eat more than just a taste of bread together with the fruit.)

Comment: +1 I always wondered why no one suggests doing that for maror (first little bite of lettuce with a crumb of matza) to avoid the bracha rishona issues.

Comment: Tos Berachot 39a cites Ri as requiring a Borei Nefashot on less than a Kezayit. I wonder if we can systematically pin the Ri on a consistently strong "Asur Leihanot Meiolam Hazeh Belo Berakh" potion.

Answer (score 1):

*Don't eat it* - **is the chosid way to do** .

*eat it without a brocha* -**is the halocho**.

*To say shehakol* - **is forbidden**
(shehakol you can only say if you know (100%) you need to say a brocho

*Some other option* - **go learn**.
 you can start with the comments on the question,

See  http://www.chabad.org/3330690/
And  12 and 14  here http://www.chabad.org/3330569/

Comment: Can you provide some sources?

Comment: @AniYodea http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/15/177/index.htm - 12 and 14 here http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/14/168/index.htm

Comment: @AniYodea same Source in English - http://www.chabad.org/3330690/ ||| 12 and 14 here http://www.chabad.org/3330569/